# iOS google analytics implementation error

Tags: ios, cordova, google-analytics

i have a phone gap iOS application already finished, and i wanted to implement google analytics in it. i have download the GA sdk 3.07, and i follow the steps and everything is ok.
on running on device i have an error that no @interface GAITrackerViewController declare the method webviewdidfinshloading, so ia disabled and i run, its run but i don't the web page created, i only see a white screen, i went to google analytics site, the site did track my application. so i replace

```
@interface MainViewController : GAITrackedViewController
@end
```

by

```
@interface MainViewController : CDVViewControler
@end
```

but i can't track the application.
i am beginner in iOS and i need help.
thx

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to manage the tracking manually, since your MainViewController must inherit CDVViewController.

In your controller after initializing your tracker you can try something like :

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"appview", kGAIHitType, @"Home Screen", kGAIScreenName, nil];
[tracker send:params];
```

Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/advanced) for more information

Comment: i try it, i have this error : use of undeclared identifier 'kGAIHitType'??

Comment: @user3459064 Try importing GAIFields.h

Comment: @user3459064 Then it would be nice to accept the answer !